# Awk: filter files based on maximum in column group

Tags: linux, sorting, awk

I'm trying to filter (or move) folders based on a maximum value in each group in Linux...

**For Example:** List of filenames in a folder and I'd like to move the one with the greatest Value by Code after sorting by SN,Code,Date

```
SN-Code-Date-Value  
01-2L-20200417-153542  
01-2L-20200417-155640  --> move to folder  
01-43-20200511-192316  
01-43-20200521-165949  
01-43-20200521-185815  --> move to folder
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything on your own? Askers are expected to show their failed/incomplete attempts.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for how to format your question and [ask] for what information to provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sort by keys and timestamp and pick the first record by `awk`, which will be the first since timestamp sorting in reverse order.

```
$ sort -t- -k1,2 -k3,4r file | awk -F- '!a[$1,$2]++'
```

note that this is comparing dates as well, if you want date to be part of the key, add `$3` to lookup key as well in the script.

Comment: `sort -t- -k1,2 -k3,4r file | uniq -w15` works as well, the `-w15` telling uniq to only compare the first 15 characters.

Comment: yes will do, if the first two fields are also in fixed size format

Comment: Thanks soo much! I added the copy so the final looks like:
$ cp `ls | sort -t- -k1,2 -k3,4r | awk -F- '!a[$1,$2]++'` /<dir>/